Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found catalog_product_bundle_stock_index
I'm encountering this error repeatedly and haven't been able to resolve it.
Has anyone else experienced this or have any suggestions for a fix?
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was:
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index` SELECT `product`.`entity_id`, `cis`.`website_id`, `cis`.`stock_id`, `bo`.`option_id`, MAX(IF(e.required_options = 0, i.stock_status, 0)) AS `status` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `product`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_bundle_option` AS `bo` ON bo.parent_id = product.entity_id
 CROSS JOIN `cataloginventory_stock` AS `cis`
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_bundle_selection` AS `bs` ON bs.option_id = bo.option_id
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `i` ON i.product_id = bs.product_id AND i.website_id = cis.website_id AND i.stock_id = cis.stock_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = bs.product_id WHERE (product.entity_id IN(1600, 1601, 1603, 1604, 1605)) AND (bo.required = 0) GROUP BY `product`.`entity_id`,
    `cis`.`website_id`,
    `cis`.`stock_id`,
    `bo`.`option_id` HAVING (MAX(IF(e.required_options = 0, i.stock_status, 0)) = 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `stock_status` = VALUES(`stock_status`)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
